# remove name from dynamically created hidden input

Tags: jquery, prototype

I have a div that is being duplicated dynamically. After duping it, I need to remove the name from the hidden input only, but can't seem to be able to select it only. The majority of the file is prototype, but I have jQuery at my disposal (`jq`).

I have managed to get the name to disappear, but it clears them all out, I only want it cleared on the duplicated div.

Help appreciated.

```
function dupField(fieldName,container,dupediv){
    var container = $(container);
    var dupedDiv = $(dupediv).cloneNode(true);
    var totalins=jq("#MI_name > div").size();
    newNode=document.createElement('div');
    newNode.innerHTML=dupedDiv.innerHTML;
    newNode.setAttribute('id',dupediv+totalins);
    newNode.setAttribute('class','MI_inz');
    var inputs_txt = newNode.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var x = jq('#MI_label').val();
    for(j=0;j<inputs_txt.length;j++){//change text field names
            var nameNow = inputs_txt[j].name;
            var newName = nameNow+totalins;
            inputs_txt[j].name=newName;
            inputs_txt[j].value='';
    }
    container.appendChild(newNode);
    var nn=jq('newNode:hidden');//jQuery - this selects all the hidden's in the form-no good-only want to change hidden input in newNode
    var hid=jq(nn).attr('name','');
}
```

It's the part after `appendChild`.

some of the other things I've tried:

```
var nn=jq('newNode:input(:hidden)');
```

-

```
var nn=jq(newNode).attr('id');
jq(nn+':hidden').attr('name','');
```

etc...

I'm sure it's simple, but I can't get it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an input where attribute type equals hidden:

```
jq(newNode).find('input[type=hidden]');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
container.appendChild(newNode);
var nn=jq('newNode:hidden');
var hid=jq(nn).attr('name','');
```

You don't need to look up your new node.  You already have a reference to it.  Just use it to remove the name.

```
jq(newNode).attr('name', '');
```

Comment: i don't want to rename the node itself, but rather a hidden input within it.

Comment: Right, my bad.  Just caught that myself.  sunn0 is the right answer, as indicated.  But that's what I meant, use the existing node to find your element.